# Stop LibGDX rendering faces inside objects

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, mesh, face

So by default, libgdx renders both sides of a face. When you make a cube using a mesh (supplying vertices and indices), it renders the faces inside the cube (wasting render time).

I want to stop this because it wastes render time when I have x amount of voxels on the screen.

I have tried face culling but it's completely broken. It removes the sides and everything.

Here's my code:

```
public void setup() {
String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n" + "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" + "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n" + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" + "varying vec4 v_color;" + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" + "void main()                  \n" + "{                            \n" + "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); \n" + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoord0; \n" + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;  \n" + "}                            \n";
    String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" + "precision mediump float;\n" + "#endif\n" + "varying vec4 v_color;\n" + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" + "void main()                                  \n" + "{                                            \n" + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" + "}";

    shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    float[] vertices = { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 1, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0

    };

    short[] indices = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 11, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 15, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 19, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 23, 21, 22

    };

    texture = new Texture("texture.png");

    Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(false);

    mesh = new Mesh(true, vertices.length / 3, indices.length, VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.TexCoords(0));
    mesh.setVertices(vertices);
    mesh.setIndices(indices);

    GL40.glEnable(GL40.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //GL40.glEnable(GL40.GL_CULL_FACE);
    //GL40.glCullFace(GL40.GL_BACK);
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    cameraController.update();

    texture.bind();
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    mesh.render(shader, GL46.GL_TRIANGLES);
    shader.end();
}
```

Comment: Face culling works fine for me. Can you show your code so we can point out the problem?

Comment: Yep, just added it. I know the vertices are going to be a pain, if you do it without face culling it works though so I think I have them right.

Comment: Do the triangles in your mesh all have the same winding (counterclockwise or clockwise ordering)?

Comment: They should, I may have screwed it up at some point though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) is enabled then then primitives are discarded, dependent on the winding order of the vertex coordinates, as seen from the point of view.
For this a winding order for the front faces is defined, by [`glFrontFace`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFrontFace.xhtml). By default this is counter clockwise.
If back faces sculling is enabled:

> ```
> GL40.glEnable(GL40.GL_CULL_FACE);
> GL40.glCullFace(GL40.GL_BACK);
> ```

then the polygons which have the opposite winding order (clockwise) are discarded.

According to your vertex coordinates

> ```
> float[] vertices = { 
>     -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 
>     -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1,
>      0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1,
>      0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0,
>
>     -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0,
>     -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1,
>      0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1,
>      0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0,
>
>      0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0,
>      0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1,
>      0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1,
>      0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0,
>
>     -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0,
>     -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1,
>     -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1,
>     -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0,
>
>     -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0,
>     -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1,
>      0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1,
>      0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0,
>
>     -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0,
>     -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1,
>      0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1,
>      0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0
> };
> ```

and indices

> ```
> short[] indices = {
>      0,  1,  3,  3,  1,  2,
>      4,  5,  7,  7,  5,  6,
>      8,  9, 11, 11,  9, 10,
>     12, 13, 15, 15, 13, 14,
>     16, 17, 19, 19, 17, 18,
>     20, 21, 23, 23, 21, 22
> };
> ```

This means that the 1st, 3rd and 5th row of indices have the wrong winding order.  It has to be:

```
short[] indices = {
     0,  3,  1,  3,  2,  1,
     4,  5,  7,  7,  5,  6,
     8, 11,  9, 11,  10, 9,
    12, 13, 15, 15, 13, 14,
    16, 19, 17, 19, 18, 17,
    20, 21, 23, 23, 21, 22
};
```